# How to initialize javascript on a webpage using the datatables plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I am attempting to use a jQuery plugin called DataTables. I am new to jQuery and setting this up on my own site in as basic a way as possible to get familiar with it. On the last step on setting it up the guide says to:

"Initialize DataTables".

"All we need to do now is to tell DataTables to actually work on the page."

The code I am suppose to Initialize is the following:

```
$(document).ready( function () {
    $('#table_id').dataTable();
} );
```

I assume I am suppose to put it in a script tag in the head or right after the head like so:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    $(document).ready( function () {
        $('#table_id').dataTable();
    } );
</script>
```

sorry for such a basic question and enlightenment would be great! thanks!

Comment: Looks good, of course include the js file for the datatables plugin.  Also of course the table with an id of `table_id` should exist in your HTML

Comment: Your code does not work?

Comment: It does now. I had to enclose the initializing script in the java script tags, put it inside the head tag, and include the id of "table_id" for the table. So now that it's done and is working I can begin learning some more styling and options for it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

your scripts looks correct 
make sure you are inluding jquery and datatable pluging
you can inlude them in the `head` tag or in the end of the `body` tag best practice to inlude all your script in the end of your `body` tag before the `</body>`

and make sure to follow the right order jquery then datatables then your sctipts

and make sure the `table` is using `thead` and `tbody`

good luck and Merry Xmas